# Use arbitrary function with MyPy's TypeVar bound attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, mypy

I've recently been diving into MyPy and came across the following example from their documentation

```
from typing import TypeVar, SupportsAbs

T = TypeVar('T', bound=SupportsAbs[float])

def largest_in_absolute_value(*xs: T) -> T:
    return max(xs, key=abs)  # Okay, because T is a subtype of SupportsAbs[float].
```

Which shows mypy can be used so that generics passed in must support the abs function to pass the static type checker.

But it's not clear to me how exactly this works. For instance, I could see this being very powerful if I could specify any function a type has to support, or a range that type must fall between.

My question is as follows: **is there a way to use bound to support any random function requirement**? For instance, the type must support the `len` function? (I suspect this is possible)

**What about a range for a specific variable type** (i.e. a string shorter than 10 characters, or an int less than 100)? (I suspect this is less possible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The core rule is this: the bound needs to be some legal PEP-484 type.

Normally, all this does is let you specify that T must eventually be "filled" by either the bound, or some subclass of the bound. For example:

```
class Parent: pass
class Child(Parent): pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Parent)

def foo(x: T) -> T: return x

# Legal; revealed type is 'Parent'
reveal_type(foo(Parent()))  

# Legal; revealed type is 'Child'
reveal_type(foo(Child()))

# Illegal, since ints are not subtypes of Parent
foo(3)
```

You can do somewhat more interesting things by having your bound be a [Protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html).

Basically, suppose you have a program like this:

```
class SupportsFoo:
    def foo(self, x: int) -> str: ...

class Blah:
    def foo(self, x: int) -> str: ...

# The two types are not related, so this fails with a
# 'Incompatible types in assignment' error -- the RHS needs
# to be a subtype of the declared type of the LHS.
x: SupportsFoo = Blah()
```

These two classes are treated by mypy as being completely unrelated: they may both happen to share a function `foo` with the same signature, but `Blah` doesn't inherit from `SupportsFoo` or vice versa, so their similarity is treated as being a coincidence and so is discarded.

We can change this by turning `SupportsFoo` into a *protocol*:

```
# If you're using Python 3.7 or below, pip-install typing_extensions
# and import Protocol from there
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsFoo(Protocol):
    def foo(self, x: int) -> str: ...

class Blah:
    def foo(self, x: int) -> str: ...

# This succeeds!
x: SupportsFoo = Blah()
```

Now, this succeeds! Mypy understands that `Blah` has methods with the exact same signatures as `SupportsFoo`, and so treats it as a subtype of the former.

---

This is exactly what's happening with `SupportsAbs` -- you can examine the [definition of that type for yourself](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L99) on Typeshed, the repository of type hints for the standard library. (A copy of Typeshed is baked into every mypy release):

```
@runtime_checkable
class SupportsAbs(Protocol[_T_co]):
    @abstractmethod
    def __abs__(self) -> _T_co: ...
```

And yes, as you asked, you can also create a protocol to insist that the input type implements `__len__` using `typing.Sized`, which is defined like so:

```
@runtime_checkable
class Sized(Protocol, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __len__(self) -> int: ...
```

---

And yes, your intuition that there isn't a clean way of creating types that assert things like "this string must be 10 characters or less" or "this must be an int less then 100" is correct.

We can *kind* of hack in support for that by using an unrelated mechanism known as [Literal types](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/) by doing something like so:

```
# As before, import from typing_extensions for Python 3.7 or less
from typing import Literal

BetweenZeroAndOneHundred = Literal[
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    # ...snip...
    96, 97, 98, 99, 100,
]
```

But this is pretty hacky and practically speaking of very limited value.

The better solution is to generally just do your custom checks at runtime and use [NewType](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#newtypes):

```
from typing import NewType

LessThanOneHundred = NewType('LessThanOneHundred', int)

def to_less_than_one_hundred(value: int) -> LessThanOneHundred:
    assert value < 100
    return LessThanOneHundred(value)
```

It's not a perfect solution because it requires you to do your checks at runtime/requires you to make sure you only every "instantiate" your NewType after finishing your runtime checks, but it *is* an actually usable way of encoding the result of arbitrary runtime checks in a form the type checker will understand.

Comment: Is the `NewType` solution equivalent to [phantom-types](https://github.com/antonagestam/phantom-types)?